# how to get HiddenField Value from ascx.cs page to aspx.cs page

Tags: c#, asp.net

my ascx code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Demo.ascx.cs" Inherits="Demo" %>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidden1" runat="server" Value=""/>
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="Hiii"></asp:Label>
```

my ascx.cs code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            lbl1.Text = "Mahendra Kamble";
            hidden1.Value = "123";
        }   



    }
```

my aspx code:

```
<%@ Register TagName="TopBar" TagPrefix="CRS" Src="~/Demo.ascx" %>
---
--
<div>
        <CRS:TopBar ID="Hide" runat="server" Visible="false"/>

</div>
```

my aspx.cs code

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
        {


            //Label lb = (Label)Hide.FindControl("lbl1");
            // Response.Write("---" + lb.Text);

            //HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)Hide.FindControl("hidden1");
            //Response.Write("---" + hf.Value);
            // UserControl control = (UserControl)LoadControl("Demo.ascx");

            Demo uc = (Demo)Page.LoadControl("Demo.ascx");
            // HiddenField hf1 = (HiddenField)control.FindControl("hidden1");
            HiddenField hide = (HiddenField)uc.FindControl("hidden1");
            Response.Write("--- " + hide.Value + " Value ");
            form1.Controls.Add(uc);
        }
```

Now How should I get the Value of HiddenField i.e. hidden1.value="123" in this aspx.cs page?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value of hidden field to a view state property.
so you can set or get the value of hidden fields.